# How can I edit fields in pdf dynamically from Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, pdf, automation, pdf-form

I have to update fields in pdf dynamically from Delphi code. Is it possible to classify a textbox from a checkbox in pdf file? If so, how to update from Delphi code? Is there any third party library available under GNU license for that matter?

Comment: [`iTextPDF`](http://itextpdf.com/) looks promising to do this. It has C# API wrapper available though but the headers might be easy to translate.

Comment: But thats for C# and Java. Not for Delphi I guess

Comment: See this question on SO : [delphi-load-and-edit-pdf-documents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539260/delphi-load-and-edit-pdf-documents)

Comment: I have gone through that qn. But none of them are GNU products.

Comment: Unlikely GPL guys will wish to work with anything Adobe's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can figure out how to run PHP from within Delphi (?), there is another tool [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)  which is LGPL licensed close to GNU licensing.

If you can figure out how to call Java from Delphi, then you could try PDFBox (an Apache project so the licence might be more friendly). Not sure if this can populate form edit fields. iText after verson 2.1.7 requires a bought license AFAIK (GNU Affero General Public License version 3 as per the web site) so might be the same for iTextPDF. It can certainly populate forms.

So far as Delphi tools, Gnostice make a commercial tool that seems to have promise to do but you have to pay.

Comment: I cannot use any other programming language, the entire application is in Delphi, and now I cannot find anyway to call other languages.

Comment: To call java you can use JNA see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997495/using-a-java-class-from-delphi) for an example. To call java to Delphi [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057226/how-to-use-jna-to-call-string-returning-delphi-function-from-java)