# How can I call a Delphi function that returns a string using JNA?

Tags: java, string, delphi, jna, freepascal

I'm working on calling functions from a Delphi compiled *.so file from a Java program. After some research it seems like [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) is he way to go. Before diving into some complex Delphi code, I'm trying to play with some "Hello World" code but am having trouble getting a string returned by a Delphi function.

The Delphi code (helloworld.pp):

```
library HelloWorldLib;

function HelloWorld(const myString: string): string; stdcall;
begin
  WriteLn(myString);
  Result := myString;
end;

exports HelloWorld;

begin
end.
```

I compile it from the command line with "**fpc -Mdelphi helloworld.pp**", which produces **libhelloworld.so**.

Now my Java class:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class HelloWorld {
    public interface HelloWorldLibrary extends Library {
        HelloWorldLibrary INSTANCE = (HelloWorldLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("/full/path/to/libhelloworld.so", HelloWorldLibrary.class);

        String HelloWorld(String test);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(HelloWorldLibrary.INSTANCE.HelloWorld("QWERTYUIOP"));
    }
}
```

However when I run this Java code I get:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f810318add2, pid=4088, tid=140192489072384
#
# JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libhelloworld.so+0xbdd2]  HelloWorld+0x6fea
```

Note that if I change my Delphi method (and the associated Java interface) to return a hardcoded integer, everything works great: the string I pass gets printed and I get the int back as expected.

Strangely enough, if the Delphi method returns a char, I have to write my JNA proxy as returning a byte and cast it to char manually (if I declare my interface as returning a char it prints out a garbage character).

Any idea what is going wrong here?

FYI, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, 64bits, using Sun JDK 1.7.0_10-b18, JNA 3.5.1 and Free Pascal Compiler version 2.4.4-3.1.

Comment: Can you return other `String`s from the native function than the one that was passed in?

Comment: @HannoBinder: I get the same error if I change my Delphi code to do "Result := 'HELLO';". :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Delphi or FreePascal `string` is a managed type that cannot be used as a JNA type. The [JNA documentation](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html#strings) explains that Java `String` is mapped to a pointer to a null-terminated array of 8 bit characters. In Delphi terms that is `PAnsiChar`.

So you can change the input parameter in your Pascal code from `string` to `PAnsiChar`.

The return value is more problematic. You will need to decide who allocates the memory. And whoever allocates it must also free it.

If the native code is responsible for allocating it then you'd need to heap allocate the null-terminated string. And return a pointer to it. You'd also need to export a deallocator so that the Java code can ask the native code to deallocate the heap allocated block of memory.

It is usually more convenient to allocate a buffer in the Java code. Then pass that to the native code and let it fill out the content of the buffer. This Stack Overflow question illustrates the technique, using the Windows API function `GetWindowText` as its example: [How can I read the window title with JNI or JNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173926/)

An example of this using Pascal would be like so:

```
function GetText(Text: PAnsiChar; Len: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
const
  S: AnsiString = 'Some text value';
begin
  Result := Length(S)+1;//include null-terminator
  if Len>0 then
    StrPLCopy(Text, S, Len-1);
end;
```

On the Java side, I guess the code would look like this, bearing in mind that I know absolutely nothing about Java.

```
public interface MyLib extends StdCallLibrary {
    MyLib INSTANCE = (MyLib) Native.loadLibrary("MyLib", MyLib.class);
    int GetText(byte[] lpText, int len);
}

....

int len = User32.INSTANCE.GetText(null);
byte[] arr = new byte[len];
User32.INSTANCE.GetText(arr, len);
String Text = Native.toString(arr);
```

Comment: Ahhh you're right. That brings back memories of pointers, malloc, etc that had disappeared under years of working with the JVM garbage collector...

BTW having the Delphi method return a PAnsiChar works with a JNA mapping of a String as return type (but then opens the issue of memory allocation).

Comment: The Java class looks like this:

public class HelloWorld {
 public interface HelloWorldLibrary extends Library {
  HelloWorldLibrary INSTANCE = (HelloWorldLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("/home/clevesque/Desktop/delphi/libhelloworld.so", HelloWorldLibrary.class);

  int GetText(byte[] buffer);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
  System.out.println(HelloWorldLibrary.INSTANCE.GetText(buffer));
  System.out.println(Native.toString(buffer));
 }
}

Comment: Indeed, returning `PAnsiChar` is fine modulo deallocating the memory.

Comment: It's better to directly add the size of the allocation to the java<-> pascal interface, so that the pascal code can be written in a way that never writes too much

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort That allows the caller to allocate a constant buffer, e.g. a stack allocated fixed length array. But if the expectation is that the array is always dynamically allocated, then the extra parameter serves no purpose.

Comment: My bad. I missed the construction with calling with nil.

Answer (score 0):

Besides that, using stdcall on 64-bit Linux is not entirely logical either. It probably works, since there usually is only one calling convention on a 64-bit target, but correct, it isn't. Use cdecl;

Comment: Surely calling convention decorators are just ignored for x64 targets. If the same code is ever compiled for x86 then calling convention becomes important again.

Comment: Well, that's precisely what I'm saying isn't it? Happens to be working is different from correct.