# Java with Delphi 5

Tags: java, delphi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a java class from Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997495/using-a-java-class-from-delphi)

I wrote a program in Delphi 5 years ago and I am now revisiting it.   Is it possible to write a class in Java and then use it as a component in the Delphi 5 program?  If so what is the best way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think that might work is creating an Applet in java and showing it on a web browser component from Delphi. But I don't know how can you access properties from this applet.

Comment: JNA and JNI are what he wants (see linked duplicate)