# Is it possible to use Selenium web driver with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use Selenium web driver with Delphi ?

for example can I write this C# code in Delphi :

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();    
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://example.com");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys("xxxx");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("zzzz");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("submit")).Click();
```

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, nobody has released client bindings for Delphi so far. There have been [discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/Z6gTr3DUP9E) about that a couple of years ago, however.

To be able to write WebDriver tests in Delphi, there would be to possible options:

1. Use the existing Java/.NET bindings and call them from Delphi using a [wrapper technology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997495/using-a-java-class-from-delphi), or
2. implementing a REST-client for the [WebDriver JSON/Wire Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/) in Delphi.

Option (2) sounds favorable, and given that there are tutorials like [this one](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Tutorial:_Using_the_REST_Client_Library_to_Access_REST-based_Web_Services) out there this shouldn't be too hard to accomplish.